# API Gateway + Lambda failed to handle exception

Tags: python, exception, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have Python based Lambda which is integrated with API Gateway and try to handle lambda exception below.

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/index.py",
      14,
      "handler",
      "raise Exception(err)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "Exception",
  "errorMessage": "device name existed"
}
```

I've defined HTTP status 400 of Method Response for the exception.

[image]

I also defined "Lambda Error Regex" and "Body Mapping Templates".

[image]

But the API Gateway still responses HTTP status 200 instead of 400 when my lambda raised an exception.

Anyone has idea what's going wrong. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Here is my Lambda code:

```
    raise Exception({
        "errorType" : "Exception",
        "httpStatus": 400,
        "message": err
    })
```

API Gateway will get the error like

```
{
   "stackTrace": [["/var/task/index.py", 17, "handler", "\"message\": err"]], 
   "errorType": "Exception", 
   "errorMessage": "{'message': 'device not found', 'errorType': 'Exception', 'httpStatus': 400}"
}
```

The reason why my lambda error regex didn't work is that the error message is within single quotes instead of double quotes.

After I changed the lambda error regex like below, everything works fine

```
.*'errorType': 'Exception'.*
```

Comment: This saved my day. None of the documentation mention that format. All the docs and post I could find seem to suggest the API Gateway would automatically look into the errorMessage, but you showed that is not the case.